# Setting Grails/Spring Locale during Spring Security login - how?

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security, locale

In my Grails 1.3.7 application, I store the user's language and country in a domain class.

During a (Spring Security) login, I want to set the locale for the user session to the language/country stored for this user.

I'm implementing my custom listener, registered in grails-app/spring/resources.groovy:

```
class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
    def config = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config

    void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
            User user = User.findByUsername(event.authentication.name)
            Locale locale = new Locale(user.getLanguage(), user.getCountry())

            LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale)
            HttpServletRequest request = SecurityRequestHolder.request
            HttpServletResponse response = SecurityRequestHolder.response
            LocaleResolver locRes = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request)

            locRes.setLocale(request, response, locale)
    }
}
```

My problem is that RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver returns null.

How do I set the new locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than do this in the login-step, you should create a [`LocaleResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html) implementation which can determine the correct `Locale` to use for a given `HttpServletRequest`.

Your app will need to know how to resolve the Locale for every subsequent request that the user makes. Setting the Locale in the LocaleResolver or the LocaleContextHolder manually only affects the ThreadLocal storing the Locale for the *current* request. A new request will not have the same ThreadLocal and will see an unset Locale.

It should be trivial to create an implementation which gets the currently-logged-in `UserDetails` from the Spring Security context and finds the Locale for the User (or you could store the details in Session, etc., the choice is up to you).

Comment: Thanks Matt. I can't really verify that setting the Locale in the LocaleResolver and LocaleContextHolder only affects the current request - out of curiosity, I put it into it in a "changeLanguage" Grails controller action, and after changing it, the updated Locale stays for the following requests as well. Maybe Grails does some magic there?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and made a workaround. LocaleResolver by default is `SessionLocaleResolver`. Obviously from name, it stores locale in session by key `SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME`.
So, you can set it manually after user login.
Here is my code from `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event, appCtx ->
    User.withNewSession {
        User user = User.get(event.authentication.principal.id)
        if (user?.locale) {
            HttpServletRequest request = SecurityRequestHolder.request
            // SmartConfigLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME if you use locale-configuration plugin
            WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, user.locale)
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplest way. As you see, I used a [callback closure](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/events.html#registeringCallbackClosures) instead of declaring separate class and registering bean in `resources.groovy`.
Also it worst to mention that you can save a `Locale` field instead off two separate fields for language and country.

And this line

```
User user = User.findByUsername(event.authentication.name)
```

You can rewrite to more efficient

```
User user = User.get(event.authentication.principal.id)
```

it will use a Hibernate second level cache by id and will be safe for case sensitive usernames.